# Regular expression in google spreadsheet formula

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-apps

I have this formula:

```
 query('Form Responses 1'!$A$1:$D$20,"Select B where D = 'whater'",0)
```

However, the sheet in which the responses go, are not always "Form Responses 1" but can be 2,3,4 etc..

I have tried things like

```
query('Form Responses ' & ? &'!$A$1:$D$20,"Select B where D = 'whater'",0)
```

but it doesn't work.

How should I do ? or is there a way around ?

Comment: this is not a Google-Apps-Script question but rather a [google-spreadsheet] one... please retag.

Answer (score 0):

How do you pass the sheet number (2, 3, 4 etc..) to the formula?

Try the following:

```
=QUERY(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("'Form Responses "; B1; "'!$A$1:$D$20")); "SELECT Col2 WHERE Col4 = 'whater'"; 0)
```

Comment: I don't want to pass a number I want to read in any sheet that starts with From Responses (there will be only one at a time, but the number can vary).

Comment: @Eagle1: When do you should read the sheet name, when you open the spreadsheet?